# Create several records of the same table in one click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, controller

I have a questionnaire that needs to be answered.

My model has table answers and table questions and i pass correctly but I get an error

> undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass

I just need a way to pass this array to the controller.

i think the error means that i'm passing an empty array so if you can help me with another way to write the code or edit it to be working.

my view :

```
           <%@answers_array = []%>
    <% @questionnaire.qquestions.each do |question| %>
        <strong><%=question.body %></strong>
        </br>
    <%= text_field_tag 'answers_array[]',""%> 
            <%end%>
 <p><%= link_to "Done",:controller => :answer_questionnaires, :action => :create, :params=>{:id => @questionnaire.id, :@answers=>@answers_array}  %></p>
```

my controller:

```
def create
  @questionnaire = Questionnaire.find(params[:id])
  number = 1
  @answers = params[:@answers]
  @answers.each do |answer| 
      AnswerQuestionnaire.create(:body => answer,:qquestion_id =>number)
      number = number + 1  
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be much better off creating a nested form rather than passing params around like that. There are a few good [railscasts about nested forms here](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=nested+forms).

Comment: i'm trying to tell the controller that the :@answers (which is in the controller)it's value is @answers_array(in the view) in the link_to plus theres no form this is the only loop

Comment: Ok I see now what you're trying to do. Still I would encourage you to rethink your strategy and look at those railscasts.

Comment: will give it a try and will keep you posted